# Retorno de query , Fatal error: Maximum execution [PHP]

Tags: php

```
            <tr>
              <td id="titulo">
                <a href="./visualizar" data-html="true"
                            data-trigger="hover" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="<?= $p[$i]->titulo; ?>">
                  <?php
                    $str = $p[$i]->titulo;
                    echo text_limiter_caracter($str, 32, '...');
                  ?>
                </a>
              </td>
              <td id="edital">
                <span data-html="true" data-trigger="hover" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="right" data-content="<?= $p[$i]->edital; ?>" >
                  <?php
                    $stred = $p[$i]->edital;
                    echo text_limiter_caracter($stred, 32, '...');
                  ?>
                </span>
              </td>
            </tr>

function text_limiter_caracter($str, $limit, $suffix = '...')
{
    while (substr($str, $limit, 1) != ' ') {
        $limit--;
    }

    if (strlen($str) <= $limit) {
        return $str;
    }

    return substr($str, 0, $limit + 1) . $suffix;

}
```

O sistema esta me retornando um loop indesejado , o que eu quero e retornar uma string igual a do titulo.

[image: Nao sei o que esta de errado :/]

Model
    public function listarProjetoPage($situacao, $inicio, $max) {

```
    $sql  = "SELECT t1.titulo,t3.nome as edital, t2.nome as area
             FROM projeto t1
             INNER JOIN areaconhecimento t2 on (t2.id = t1.idAreaConhecimento)
             INNER JOIN edital t3 on (t3.id = t1. ) WHERE t1.situacao = $situacao ORDER BY t1.titulo LIMIT $inicio, $max";

    $stmt = $this->conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute();

    return $stmt->fetchAll();

}
```

Controller

```
function listarProjetoPage($situacao, $inicio, $max) {

    $resultado = $this->projetos->listarProjetoPage($situacao, $inicio, $max);
    return $resultado;
}
```

Comment: O que pretendes obter com esse loop ?

Comment: Desejo retornar uma palavra encurtada assim como no titulo...

Comment: Por esse código não dá saber o que está causando o erro, basicamente ele diz, o trabalho que o php deveria fazer em até 30 segundos demorou mais que isso. É uma consulta? poste ela.

Comment: A linha 143 é `echo text_limiter_caracter($stred, 32, '...');` ?

Comment: Erro resolvido .

Comment: Para encurtar uma palavra/frase precisas de um loop para ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    function text_limiter_caracter($str, $limit, $suffix = '...')
    {
      if (strlen($str) <= $limit) {
        return $str;
      }else{
        return substr($str, 0, $limit + 1) . $suffix;
      }
    }
```

O Erro estava no while, pois ele estava verificando por " " (espaço), e no meu primeiro edital nao havia espaço logo ele gerava um loop no while.